# Typescript - Removing milliseconds

Tags: javascript, typescript, date

In typescript, I am setting an object's date field in following way.

at: new Date("2017-06-24"+"T"+"22:00"+"Z")

Then I am sending that object as POST body to my webservice. In body, date field looks like `"at":"2017-06-24T22:00:00.000Z"`
But I want o get rid of milliseconds part. How can I do that ?

Comment: you've `zero` milliseconds in date already. no ?

Comment: yes its already zero

Comment: y dont you directly use `at: '2017-06-24T22:00Z'`, you anyway are sending a string then y do you want to assign the value of at as a new Date() instead directly generate a string with the help of date and time which you already have.

Comment: Hi @Avinash, because I tried to simplify question. I am getting date and time parts from a form input. Thats why I didnt ask question as you wrote

Comment: have a look at this [remove milliseconds from date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758963/remove-seconds-milliseconds-from-date-convert-to-iso-string)

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution in following threat ends up with milliseconds :(  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758963/remove-seconds-milliseconds-from-date-convert-to-iso-string

Comment: i have one more doubt i mean even if you are getting the date and time from a form input you can use `{inputDate}T{inputTime}Z` to generate a String.

Comment: I am using angular 2 form. and getting values like form.value.depAt and  form.value.depTime. So I am not sure putting variables side to side means concatenation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173691/discussion-between-avinash-and-luckystones).

Answer (score 1):

You can format the String you have from the form input values as

```
new Date("2017-06-24"+"T"+"22:00"+"Z").toISOString().split('.')[0]+"Z"
```

else you can directly generate the String from your form input values

```
`${this.form.value.Date}T${this.form.value.Time}Z`
```

in both the above cases you have the String output as ***2017-06-24T22:00:00Z***
 and not the Date type.
Date constructor in Js will have the milliseconds field
so it will be an issue if **at** in your Object is defined as a Date instead of a String.