# TypeScript: Remove Seconds from Date Object and Reconvert back to Date?

Tags: javascript, typescript, date

How Do I Remove Seconds from Date Object and Reconvert back to Date?

```
let testDate = new Date(2020, 05, 03, 1, 2);
```

This answer converts to ISO String, I dont want that, but return an actual Date.

[Remove Seconds/ Milliseconds from Date convert to ISO String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758963/remove-seconds-milliseconds-from-date-convert-to-iso-string#:~:text=There%20is%20no%20need%20for,(0%2C0)%3B%20document).

Comment: You can't remove seconds from a Date object as it doesn't have any. A Date is just a time value, an offset in milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. You can adjust the time value so that the seconds and milliseconds are zero using [*setSeconds*](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setSeconds), whether or not seconds are displayed depends formatting options when displaying it as a string (see [*How to format a JavaScript date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date?r=SearchResults&s=1|1450.4192)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var date = new Date();

date.setSeconds(0, 0);

console.log(date);
```

Comment: How is that different to the highest voted answer linked in the OP?

Comment: @RobG Nothing, sorry, I did not pay attention to that answer :(